# Expressing the magnitude of a vector difference in indicial notation

Tags: index-notation

I'm trying to express the following relation in indicial notation
$$
|\vec{u} - \vec{v}_p| \, .
$$

The only way I found out is replacing the difference above by
$$
\vec{u} - \vec{v}_p = \vec{v}_r \, ,
$$
then one can write
$$
|\vec{u} - \vec{v}_p| = |\vec{v}_r| = (v_{r,i}v_{r,i})^{1/2} \, .
$$

**Is there anyway to express the vector difference directly in the indicial notation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always do
$$|\vec{u}-\vec{v}_p|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(u_i-v_{p,i})^2},$$
so that you don't need the helper vector $\vec{v}_r$. Another option is to use the Einstein summation convention, and just write
$$|\vec{u}-\vec{v}_p|=\sqrt{(u_i-v_{p,i})(u_i-v_{p,i})},$$
but you'd have to make sure your readers were aware that you were invoking the convention.

Comment: I agree with the first suggestion (index at the summation is $i$ instead of $j$), and i think it's clear. I've also thought of your second suggestion but i don't clearly see the summation invoking in this form.

Comment: Well, I see it now! Opening up the terms it becomes clear. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo - I've fixed it.